# I have a question, if I used firebase facebook login how can get username or email?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have a question, if I used firebase facebook login how can get username or email?

when I clicked the facebook login button, how can add username and email into realtime database?

Comment: make a facebook GraphRequest to fetch the username and email.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you can do that with Facebook.
[AdditionalUserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo) class contains `getUsername()` method but that works only with Twitter and Github.